# problem with j index in this C function but only in the second loop, not the first

Tags: c, string

I need to create this function: "count number of vowels and consonants and put them in *dstV and *dstC, i.e vowels, and consonants"

this is my full solution:

```
int count_vowels_consonants(unsigned char* src, int* dstV, int* dstC) {
    if (src == "") {
        return -1; 
    }
    char consonants[] = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ";
    int vowels = 0; int cons = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; src[i] != 0; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; consonants[j] != 0; j++) {
            if (src[i] == consonants[j]) {
                cons++; 
            }
        } 
    }
    dstC = &cons; 
    char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU"; 
    for (int i = 0; src[i] != 0; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; vowels[j] != 0; j++) {
            if (src[i] == vowels[j]) {
                vowels++; 
            }
        }
    }
    dstV = &vowels; 
    return 0; 

}


int main(void) {
    char src[] = "ABACEDI0O1UR"; 
    // 6 vowels, and 4 consonants
    int dstV = 0; 
    int dstC = 0; 
    int ret = count_vowels_consonants(src, &dstV, &dstC); 
    return 0; 
}
```

debugger displayed me an error in the second j index, note: not in the first (i don't know why, i've used the same loops for consonants and vowels), this is the error:
"expression must have pointer-to-object type, but it has type int"

Comment: The `if (src == "")` is never true - strings are compared with `strcmp()`. Did you mean `if (src == NULL`)? Either way, you should set the results to `0`. I see you do that in `main()` but the functionality should be self contained.

Comment: You use the symbol 'vowels' twice, that can't work.
`int vowels = 0;`
`char vowels[] = "aeiouAEIOU";`

Comment: `dstC = &cons` does not do what you want. It should be `*dstC = cons`